# In Excel, how to convert HTML text to regular text in multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel workbook with multiple sheets, each having multiple cells containing HTML text. How can I convert this text directly to regular text with all the formatting defined in HTML tags. Is it possible to have a macro which can scan all such cells and convert them at once?

Answer (score 0):

try the below function to strip all the html tags (except Bold and break) and to get regular text by parsing the html text to this function like striphtml(your html text).

```
Function StripHTML(sInput As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim sOut As String
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "<(?!/?(?:br|b)\b)[^>]*>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.
    End With
    sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
    StripHTML = sOut
    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: But this will only remove the tags from text, the required formatting will be gone like line break, bold text etc.

Comment: Pls check the edited code for stripping html except bold and break